# Single Mass Oscillator. ODE with more conditions than variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conditional-expectation, initial-value-problems

i have the following ODE of a single mass oscillator with a spring and a damper:

$m*\ddot{s}=-d*\dot{s}-c*s+m*g$

where $m = 5$, $g=10$
$c$ & $d$ are variable

The ODE is now :

$\ddot{s}=-\frac{d}{5}*\dot{s}-\frac{c}{5}*s+10$

I have 2 intitial conditions that have to apply:

$s(0)=0$

$\dot{s}(0)=0$

Now to my question: If I calculate the solution of the oscillation (e.g. with Matlab) I get

$s(t,c,d)$ which is still depending on the variables $c$ an $d$

Further i can calculate the derivatives of the solution depending on $c$ and $d$

$\dot{s}(t,c,d)$

$\ddot{s}(t,c,d)$

My problem is, that i have 3 conditions for 2 unknown variables, which makes the linear system of equations needed to solve for $c$ and $d$ overdetermined.

$s(t_{max})=s_{max}$

$\dot{s}(\ddot{s}=0)=\dot{s}_{max}$

$\dot{s}(t_{max})=0$

How do I solve for $c$ and $d$ so that all the conditions including the initial conditions are met and valid for this ODE?

Comment: Typically for such a problem, $c$ and $d$ are constants, and although arbitrary, are assumed to be known values, not sure what the case is for your specific problem; it seems that you state they are variables though.

Comment: It is an optimization problem to optimize c and d. But for that, I need to solve for c and d first.

Comment: What are you optimizing?

Comment: thats not determined yet